# EditText loosing curosr after showing softkeyboard

Tags: android

I'm using an custom emoji Icons and I use a button to show the icons layout, and when the user clicks on the editText I show the keyboard again, below is my code,

```
Emojicon.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()) {
            emojLayOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(Emojicon, 0);
            Emojicon.requestFocus();

        }
        return true; 
    }
});
```

The problem I'm having is that I lose the cursor, copy, cut and paste.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it, I had to use setOnFocusChangeListener and clear the focus on the emoji button.

```
emojButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        emojLayOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext.getWindowToken(), 0);

        getContentResolver().notifyChange(Uri.parse(Commons.COMMENT_CONTENT_TYPE), null);
        edittext.clearFocus();
    }
});

edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {

                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.showSoftInput(edittext,
                            InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                    emojLayOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            }
        });
```